# Arduino WiFi ESP8266 log data with conditions fails

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I'm sorry if the title is not 100% precise, I'll try to explain it better: I am using a SparkFun ESP8266 wifi module programmed with Arduino. It gets data from a humidity and temperature sensor DHT22 and logs those data to my Firebase Database (through a Flask Application) ONLY if specific conditions are met:

- temperature > 16C and difference from last temp. >= 1C
- OR: temp. <= 16C and difference from last temp. >= 5C
- OR: humidity < 60% and difference from last hum. >= 1%
- OR: hum. >= 60% and difference from last hum. >= 5%

```cpp
int deltaT = abs(temp-temp1);
      int deltaH = abs(hum-hum1);

      if (
          (temp1 > 16.0 && deltaT >= 1)
          || (temp1 <= 16.0 && deltaT >= 5)
          || (hum1 < 60.0 && deltaH >= 1)
          || (hum1 >= 60.0 && deltaH >= 5)
        ){
// ...
}
```

The problem is that no matter what the results of temperature and humidity are, my device is still logging most of the data (just sometimes it works). I don't know if the problem is with my logic (if statement) or something else.

This is my full code, can you help me troubleshooting?

```cpp
#include <DHT.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <DNSServer.h>            //Local DNS Server used for redirecting all requests to the configuration portal
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>     //Local WebServer used to serve the configuration portal
#include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager WiFi Configuration Magic

#define DHTPIN 4
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);

float temp;
float hum;
float temp1;
float hum1;

int red_light_pin = 16;
int green_light_pin = 12;
int blue_light_pin = 13;
int switch_pin = 15;

// Server, file, and port
const char hostname[] = "laundryireland.tk";
const String uri = "/write_data?";
const String arguments[3] = {"serial=","&temp=","&hum="};
const int port = 80;

bool powerOn;

String serialNumber;

WiFiClient client;


void RGB_color(int red_light_value, int green_light_value, int blue_light_value)
 {
  analogWrite(red_light_pin, red_light_value);
  analogWrite(green_light_pin, green_light_value);
  analogWrite(blue_light_pin, blue_light_value);
}

void setup() {

  powerOn = true;

  pinMode(red_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue_light_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switch_pin,INPUT);
  RGB_color(0,0,255);

  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFiManager wifiManager;

  //Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  delay(100);

  //Connect to WiFi
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  wifiManager.autoConnect();
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {

    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }


  //Show that we are connected
  Serial.println("Connected!");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  serialNumber = WiFi.macAddress();
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long next = 0;

  int switch_state = digitalRead(switch_pin);
  int count = 0;

  while (switch_state == HIGH){
    count = count + 1;
    delay(1000);
    switch_state = digitalRead(switch_pin);
    if (count >= 3 && powerOn == true) {
      powerOn = false;
      RGB_color(255,0,0);
      Serial.println("Eco-mode active");
      break;
    } else if (count >= 3 && powerOn == false) {
      powerOn = true;
      RGB_color(0,255,0);
      Serial.println("Full throttle!");
      break;
    }
  }

  if (powerOn == true){
    unsigned long now = millis();

    if (now > next) {
      temp1 = dht.readTemperature();
      hum1 = dht.readHumidity();
      while (temp1 == NAN || hum1 == NAN){
          RGB_color(255,0,0);
          delay(5000);
          temp1 = dht.readTemperature();
          hum1 = dht.readHumidity();
        }

      int deltaT = abs(temp-temp1);
      int deltaH = abs(hum-hum1);

      if (
          (temp1 > 16.0 && deltaT >= 1)
          || (temp1 <= 16.0 && deltaT >= 5)
          || (hum1 < 60.0 && deltaH >= 1)
          || (hum1 >= 60.0 && deltaH >= 5)
        ){

        temp = temp1;
        hum = hum1;

        RGB_color(0,255,0);
        Serial.print("Temperature: ");
        Serial.println(temp);
        Serial.print("Humidity: ");
        Serial.println(hum);

        Serial.println("Testing flask ");
        if ( client.connect(hostname,port) == 0 ) {
          Serial.println("Flask Test Failed!");
        } else {
          Serial.println("Flask Test Success!");
          client.print("GET " + uri + arguments[0] + serialNumber +
                        arguments[1] + temp +
                        arguments[2] + hum +
                        " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                        "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n" +
                        "Connection: close\r\n" +
                        "\r\n");
          delay(500);

        }

        client.stop();
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("Connection closed");

      } else {
        Serial.println("temp or hum not changed");
        RGB_color(255,255,0);
      }
      next = now + 600000;
    } else {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

}
```

This is an example of data that shouldn't have been recorded because they don't follow my if statement logic (the numbers on top are the timestamps):

[image: example data]

Comment: name examples that pass your if statemen't but shouldn't in your opinion

Comment: Hi @Piglet I updated my question to include an example :)

Comment: and this is a continuous problemw while it is running or do you restart the device between those false measurements?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct.  When I saw the data excerpt I ask myself; where are the pressure and wind_speed values coming from? Is there a complex logic on the server, that merges the output from the program above with some other output? Is it possible that the entries are inserted, without a trigger from the program. (OK, perhaps they are fixed values). I also can not find a correlation between the timestamps (seconds?) and the intervals your program should deliver output. Have you checked the serial output, if the program really enters the "if" case?

Comment: @Piglet no there is no restart of the device, it's a continuous running issue.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer pressure, wind speed etc. are the result of an external API call: every 10 minutes, the device make a request to a flask application running remotely on a server and this request is the trigger for the API call and the database log. the timestamp is in epoch style: if you copy paste them into this website, it translate them into date and time: https://www.epochconverter.com Actually now that I think about it, it seems that the interval is 15-16seconds and not 10minutes :-/

Comment: `tmp` and `hum` are uninitialized btw. That will give you high deltas in your first run as you'll calculate with some random garbage values from those memory locations

Comment: @Piglet that's ok in the first run, but then it should use the previous value, right?

Comment: yes. just make it a habit of assigning a value befor you do any operations.

Comment: @Piglet apparently, assigning the value to the variables have solved my issue! Please post your comment as an answer ;-)

Comment: I completely agree with Piglet's advice to give variables a well defined state before they are used, but I can not imagine, why uninitialized variables should cause your observations. Perhaps I'm missing something. And as you remarked in the answer of my last comment, the entries in the result list  are made every ~15th second. The `if ( now > next )`  is only valid every 600 seconds = 10 Minutes. That' what I meant with I saw no correlation.

Comment: As you commented to the correct answer, there might be a problem with the power supply. That can be the solution, Each time the ESP sends, its power breaks down and it resets, The program starts from new and sends again, and so on. Piglet had an idea of that. See his second comment.

Comment: Yes guys you're right, I noticed only later that day that the variable assignment fixed my issue because I was testing it with the ESP connected to my computer. I tried using the power bank and the problem persisted. It was subtle to spot also because the ESP doesn't always crash so sometimes the device work as expected. I actually wrote a post on the SparkFun technical support forum here: https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=123&t=51117 regarding how to find an appropriate power bank for my project but I haven't got any answer yet. I would appreciate if you know the answer :)

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer that makes sense as the uninitalized variables are only a problem in the first run. a frequent reset would cause this problem over and over. I couldn't find a cause in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I really appreciate the help given. Apparently the problem was with the use of a common power bank for smartphones and tablets which apparently has a safety feature that turn it off when not enough power is drawn. This triggered in my device an annoying rebooting loop. I order a specific low current power bank from SparkFun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14367

This should work just fine. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this line will yield the expected result:

```
while (temp1 == NAN || hum1 == NAN)
```

since `NAN == NAN` is supposed to always return false, the condition is always false and the loop is never entered, which means you could or could not have consistent values from the first measurement attempt (before the `while`).

try

```
while (isnan(temp1) || isnan(hum1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` and `hum` are uninitialized variables.

So in your first run you'll calculate `deltaH` and `deltaT` based on random garbage values from that memory locations. That way, chances of getting high delta values are close to 100%.

So you'll have at least 2 conditions that are true due to high delta values.

To avoid things like that, make it a habit to assign values to variables befor you do any operations with them. This gives you a known, well defined situation.

To debug things like this, just print every value that is part of your condition!
If values are off, find out why and fix the cause.

Comment: Also I want to add that one of the problems could be an inadequate power source. (always check the battery requirements)